# Is there a theoretical limit for the Dielectric Constant

Tags: capacitance, material-science, dielectric

If we're being pedantic, it's a [Dielectric Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_optics), and I know that it changes with both temperature and frequency, but the question remains... How would one calculate the theoretical maximum Dielectric Constant for a capacitor? Assume the field and the material may be thoughtfully oriented, our device has access to sophisticated temperature control, and the frequency may be chosen.

Just to pre-empt you, here's a [very high dielectric constant material](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986JEMat..15..201P).

Comment: Wow.  Why aren't they using this to make batacitors?